# How to update a current row on Parse.com using a Curl REST API?

Tags: php, sql-server, curl, parse-platform, jira-rest-api

I am new to executing curl statements to update my database on Parse.com. I am able to add new rows to my class without a problem by using POST. Now... I am wondering how to update a current row in my Parse database by fetching the objectId and then updating my Parse database.  *I want to make sure that I am querying by the correct id and then update the status.

---

I am on the right track.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: my_id" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: my_key" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'keys=SiteID,site_status' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyClassName
```

How do I turn this GET method containing the objectId and put it into Parse by using it at the end of the PUT method?

output from curl:
{"SiteID":"MOCMBS0006","site_status":"Online","createdAt":"2014-06-05T19:58:26.843Z","updatedAt":"2014-06-18T22:34:39.779Z","objectId":"randomobjectid"}

Can anyone please help me? Thank you in advance!!! Any advice would be appreciated. :)

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the docs here:  https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-updating

```
curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: app-id-here" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: rest-api-key" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":73453}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm
```

Note the PUT method at the top, and the objectId at the end of the URL.  You pass in only the fields you wish to modify.

Comment: "I am wondering how to update a current row in my Parse database without having to use the objectID generated by Parse" - is what I was aiming for. I currently do not have access to the objectId generated by parse when I am executing this command. Is there a way to query in a PUT?

Comment: No, you have to query first.

Comment: How do I use a queried GET method and then call a PUT method?

Comment: Get the object id from the results of your query.

Comment: I am having a hard time finding how to fetch the objectID from my GET method. How do I call/include on my GET method to retrieve the objectID result? is it like --data-urlencode 'keys=objectID, site_id' \

Comment: you're having trouble with basic REST stuff... maybe you should be using a native SDK that makes these things easier.  https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints

Comment: How am I supposted to get the ID when I now get the error: {"code":105,"error":"the objectId key is a reserved word"} when I type in: curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: my_id" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: my_key" \
  -G \ 
 --data-urlencode ‘keys=objectId, SiteID, site_status ‘
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ClientCompanyInfo

Comment: don't pass a keys parameter if you can't get a simple query to work.. it's not a valid entry to keys, it is always returned.

Comment: I just got my curl to work properly. I just updated my code above with the output. How do I turn this GET method containing the objectId and put it into Parse by using it at the end of my PUT method?